# Problema al declarar e incializar arreglos de Objetos

Tags: c++, array, poo, clase, constructor

Tengo una clase llamada Pokemon, en donde le puse 2 constructores, el primero es de iniciallización y el otro recibe el nombre de un pokemon y lo completa

```
class Pokemon{

    private:

        string type;
        string advantage1;
        string advantage2;
        string resistance1;
        string resistance2;
        string resistance3;
        float damageattack;
        float health;
        string name;

    public:
        //Constructor

        Pokemon(float health, float damageattack, string type, string advantage1, string advantage2, string resistance1, string resistance2, string resistance3, string name){
            this->type = type;
            this->advantage1 = advantage1;
            this->advantage2 = advantage2;
            this->health = health;
            this->damageattack = damageattack;
            this->name = name;
        }

        Pokemon(string name){
            this->name=name;
            if(name == "Caterpie"){
                this->type="Bug";
                this->advantage1 = "Grass";
                this->advantage2 = "Psychic";
                this->resistance1 = "Fighting";
                this->resistance2 = "Grass";
                this->resistance3 = "Ground";
                this->health = 393;
                this->damageattack = 55;
            }

            else if(name == "Metapod"){
                this->type="Bug";
                this->advantage1 = "Grass";
                this->advantage2 = "Psychic";
                this->resistance1 = "Fighting";
                this->resistance2 = "Grass";
                this->resistance3 = "Ground";
                this->health = 419;
                this->damageattack = 45;
            }
}
```

Ahora en la función principal quiero instanciar un arreglo de la clase Pokemon, pero me envía un error.No me permite compilar.

```
int main(){
    Pokemon p1[2] = {"Metapod","Caterpie"};
}
```

**¿Cual es el problema?, supongo que tiene que ver con los 2 constructores**

Este es el error que me sale.

```
error: conversion from 'const char [8]' to non-scalar type 'Pokemon' requested
error: conversion from 'const char [9]' to non-scalar type 'Pokemon' requested
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una cadena de dos conversiones implícitas definidas por el usuario:

1. `const char *` ⇒ `std::string`
2. `std::string` ⇒ `Pokemon`

Cadenas más largas de una sola conversión implicita definida por el usuario son prohibidas. De hecho el compilador no las ve.

¿Qué puedes hacer?

1. Definir otro constructor, `Pokemon (const char*)`.
2. Definir el arreglo con conversiones explicitas:

   ```
   Pokemon p1[2] = {Pokemon("Metapod"),Pokemon("Caterpie")};
   ```
3. Definir el arreglo con cadenas `std::string` convertidas explicitamente:

   ```
   Pokemon p1[2] = {std::string("Metapod"), std::string*("Caterpie")};
   ```
4. Definir el arreglo con [literales de `std::string`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

   ```
   using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
   Pokemon p1[2] = {"Metapod"s, "Caterpie"s};
   ```